# Wordpress retrieving wrong featured images

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site which has 2 blocks with post teasers from 2 different categories. One block (cat = 8) displays well, but the other one displays incorrect featured images.

Here is the code of the page containing the 2 blocks. I have 2 more separate pagina for displaying the posts but the problem is the same there.

```
<div style="margin: 0; width: auto;">
                <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #444;">Nieuws</h4>
                <span class="more-news">
                    <a href="nieuws">meer nieuwsberichten</a>
                </span>
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => '2', 'cat' => '9') ); ?>
                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : ?>
                    <div class="unit-100 group teaser">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                            $id = $the_query->post->ID;
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id,array(100,100));
                            $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(__('(lees meer…)'));
                        } else { 
                            $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php the_excerpt(__('(lees meer…)'));
                        } ?>    
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; 
                wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
                </div>
            <div class="unit-40">
            <div class="donate">
                <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #444;">Doneer nu!</h4><?php echo do_shortcode('[IDEAL fip_referentie="The Blue Goat Donatie"]'); ?>
                </div>
            <div class="stories">
                <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #444;">Bijzondere verhalen uit Oeganda</h4>
                <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[contentblock id=bijzondere-verhalen]'); ?></p>

                <?php $the_query2 = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => '1', 'cat' => '8') ); ?>
                <div class="">
                        <?php while ($the_query2 -> have_posts()) :
                        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                            the_post_thumbnail(array(350,350));
                            $the_query2 -> the_post(); ?>                           
                            <span class="story-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></span>
                        <?php } else {
                            $the_query2 -> the_post(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Lees meer....</a>
                        <?php }
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: This is a unique situation. Paste code your using for full slider. It's likely just an incorrect category ID being pulled.

Comment: try toggling this, to just 1. showposts' => '2',

Comment: One post with still the incorrect featured image.

Comment: I still didn't resolve this problem!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**1.)** Make sure your pulling in correct Category ID. Check within WP dashboard and code.

**2.)** Maybe something like this: *(anymore code related to this, we can see? Perhaps in functions.php?)*

```
              <?php $the_query1 = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => '1', 'cat' => '9') ); ?>
                <div class="">
                        <?php while ($the_query1 -> have_posts()) :
                        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                            the_post_thumbnail(array(350,350));
                            $the_query1 -> the_post(); ?>                           
                            <span class="story-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></span>
                        <?php } else {
                            $the_query1 -> the_post(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Lees meer....</a>
                        <?php }
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: In my code the_query2 is the one pulling the right image. Its the_query thats going wrong. And i have only enabled thumbnails in functions.php.

Comment: OK. Let's check out your relevant functions.php code. Please add that.

Comment: Also, what is the ultimate outcome goal. Might have another alternative for you.

Comment: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Comment: SO, what displays then?

Comment: Pages "Nieuws" and "Het geitje vertelt" have the same problem.